Radiation power emmited by a material with two different temperatures
Let's consider a cylindrical sample of a solid material surrounded by air. From $0 \leq r \leq r_1$ the temperature of the material is $T_1$ and from $r_1 < r \leq R$, $T=T_0$ which is also the temperature of the air that surrounds de sample. I need to find the power lost due to radiation of this sample, using Stefan-Boltzmann's Law for a grey body :
\begin{equation}
P=qA= e \sigma T^4 A
\end{equation}
my problem is I don't know which surfaces do I need to consider for each temperature.
I dont know if I have to consider only the surface of the sample itself  - finding the power lost through the covers (the surface with $T_1$ + the surface with $T_0$) and the side of the cylinder ($T_0$) - or if I should consider this problem equivalent to two cylinders, one cylinder with radius $r_1$ with $T=T_1$ and one cylinder with a hole of radius $r_1$ with $T=T_0$ and then calculating the power for each cylinder using the whole surface of each piece.
I'll be thankful for any help :)

I'm having trouble making sense of this. So this is a solid cylinder consisting of two materials? How can the inner and outer materials have different temperatures when there should be heat transfer between them by conduction? The only radiant is that emitted by the outer surface.

@BobD, Not sure I understand the question either,* but I'm imagining an object that was instantaneously assembled from two pieces, each of which had its own distinct, uniform temperature at that instant. [*And, I definitely would not be capable of answering it even if I did understand it.]

If the temperature of the body varies over the surface (Which, if I understand your question correctly, would be the case on the top and the bottom of the cylinder), you need to replace the temperature $T$ with a function $T(A)$ on the surface of the body. The Stefan-Boltzmann law then takes the form
$$
P = \int \epsilon\sigma T(A)^4 dA
$$
where the integral is taken over entire surface of the body. This may look complicated at first, but in your case, reduces to a rather simple form.
As an aside, this equation is obviously only true if we neglect heat conduction - this can be reasonably done if we assume that all calculations take place in an infinitesimal time interval, or that all involved heat capacities are large. If you assume an infinitesimal time interval, remember that (physically) power is also a function of time, and that your results may not be universally meaningful unless you account for heat conduction and integrate over time as well.
